# DPDK: MPLS packet processing

Tags: dpdk, mellanox, mpls

I am trying to build a multi-RX-queue dpdk program, using RSS to split the incoming traffic into RX queues on a single port. Mellanox ConnectX-5 and DPDK Version 19.11 is used for this purpose. It works fine when I use IP over Ethernet packets as input. However when the packet contains IP over MPLS over Ethernet, RSS does not seems to work. As a result, all packets belonging to various flows (with different `src` & `dst` IPs, ports) over MPLS are all sent into the same RX queue.

My queries are

1. Is there any parameter/techniques in DPDK to distribute MPLS packets to multiple RX queues?
2. Is there any way to strip off MPLS tags (between Eth and IP) in hardware, something like `hw_vlan_strip`?

My Port configuration is

```js
const struct rte_eth_conf default_port_conf = {
    .rxmode = {
            .hw_vlan_strip  = 0,    /* VLAN strip enabled. */
            .header_split   = 0,    /* Header Split disabled. */
            .hw_ip_checksum = 0,    /* IP checksum offload disabled. */
            .hw_strip_crc   = 0,    /* CRC stripping by hardware disabled. */
    },
    .rx_adv_conf = {
            .rss_conf = {
                    .rss_key = NULL,
                    .rss_key_len = 0,
                    .rss_hf = ETH_RSS_IP,
            },
    } };
```

Comment: @rakimbhatt did you check the answer and tried RTE_FLOW?

Comment: I have humbly request editors like `https://stackoverflow.com/users/1364007/wai-ha-lee,  and https://stackoverflow.com/users/2664350/piet-t` to help me understand `reject in question, especially when the question is specifically to POP/STRIP MPLS and then distribute to multiple queues. Question is not about MPLS processing (match MPLS id and take a specific action. but instead, pop MPLS irrespective of value if present. Seems very odd behaviour `as there is the real difference between MPLS processing vs MPLS stripping (as the requirement is not to process MPLS packet, but pop MPLS header).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement of `POP_MPLS` and `RSS on MPLS` can be activated via `RTE_FLOW` for supported NIC PMD. But `mellanox mxl5 PMD` supports only `RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_OF_PUSH_VLAN & RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_OF_PUSH_VLAN`. Only options supported for tunneled packets by `mxl5 PMD` are `MPLSoGRE, MPLSoUD`. **Hence POP MPLS in HW via PMD is not possible on MXL5 PMD for DPDK 19.11 LTS**

For any PMD `RSS` is reserved for `outer/inner IP address` along with `TCP/UDP/SCTP port numbers`. Hence I have to interpret `RSS for MPLS` as `I would like to distribute/ spread packets with different MPLS to various queues`. This can be achieved by again using `RTE_FLOW` for `RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_MPLS` and action field as `RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_QUEUE`. Using `mask/range fields` one can set patterns which can satisfy condition as `2 ^ 20 (MPLS id max value) / number of RX queues`. **hence the recommendation is to use RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_MPLS from RTE_FLOW and RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_QUEUE. But there is no IP/PORT RSS hashing for the same.**

to test the same you can use

1. DPDK testpmd and set the `flow rules` or
2. make use of RTE_FLOW code snippet from [rte_flow link](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/howto/rte_flow.html)

note: for `POP MPLS` I highly recommend to use `PTYPES` to identify the metadata and use `RX-callabck` to modify the packet header.